# iOS UIButton isEnabled always returns NO

Tags: ios, uibutton

I've a normal UIButton defined in XIB, when I try to enable it from its outlet in the view controller code I always get false, this code:

```
[self.abutton setEnabled:YES];
NSLog(@"%i",[self.abutton isEnabled]);
```

always logs 0.

It seems that setEnable:YES has no effect or that I'm not checking button status in the right way.

What I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: Have u connected outlet ?

Comment: It seems that your button is nil.

Comment: First you should check your button object using NSLog then see what comes in it.